# How to accommodate changed yahoo mail password on iPad?

Tags: ipad, email, password

My friend has an iPad. I have never used an iPad, but am trying to help her set things up better -- so it's definitely a case of the blind leading the blind.

My friend reads her yahoo mail on her iPad.  Her iPad remembers the password.  However, she herself has forgotten her yahoo mail password, which makes life difficult -- she cannot read her yahoo mail on her phone or on her laptop.

1. How can she change her yahoo password?
2. Once she has changed her yahoo password, how can she teach her iPad the new password, so she can still read her email on the iPad without having to type in her password?

Comment: It depends how old her yahoo account is and whether she has a rescue email address or challenge questions or if she told yahoo her mobile number.  Basically this has nothing to do with the iPad, you just need to visit yahoo mail in a browser and reset the password, once that's done and the old password fails the iPad will ask for and remember the new password.

Comment: We did a reset.  The iPad didn't ask for the new password -- it just failed to connect.  The second paragraph by @BrianM. worked, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tyson mentioned, your friend will obviously need to reset her Yahoo password through Yahoo directly. Once that's done:

If she's pulling her email in the Apple Mail app, she can update the password in Settings (the gear-like icon) > Mail, Contacts, Calendars. Once she navigates there, she needs to select Yahoo under the account list, then select the top "Account - (email address) >" option which will then give her the opportunity to enter her new password.

If she's using Yahoo's own "Yahoo Mail" iOS app, I'd imagine that the settings are within the app itself (sorry, I don't use Yahoo Mail anymore).

Comment: Actually a password dialogue will pop up as soon as the iPad realizes old password is no longer valid.

Comment: @Tyson - It didn't pop up for us, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

It is about yahoo settings, go to your yahoo account from a PC and in security settings, tick the option that says "let less secure connection". That's it.